# How to deploy the subnets from one resource group into existing virtual network located in different resource group using ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, subnet, azure-virtual-network

I am working on Azure Resource Manager Templates, Currently I developed ARM templates for NSG, Route table and subnets with NSG and UDR.

I wrote the below lines of code for adding the Subnets along with NSG’s and UDR’s into existing virtual network.

```
"resources": [{
  "apiVersion": "2017-10-01",
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
  "copy": {
    "name": "subnetCopy",
    "mode": "serial",
    "count": "[length(parameters('subnetNames'))]"
  },
  "name": "[ concat( parameters('existingVNETName'), '/', parameters('subnetNames')[copyIndex()] ) ]",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "properties": {
    "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnetAddresses')[copyIndex()]]",
    "networkSecurityGroup": {
      "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('subnetNSGs')[copyIndex()])]"
    },
    "routeTable": {
      "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/routeTables', parameters('subnetUDRs')[copyIndex()])]"
    }
  }
}]
```

The above code will work only if the virtual network, NSG and UDR are in the same resource group. But whenever I deployed the above code into different resource group then I am getting the error like “virtual network resource not found in this resource group.” Actually the virtual network located in other resource group with same location.

Can anyone suggest me how to modify the above code based on my above requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Template deployments have a resourceGroup scope - so you have to deploy that template to the same resourceGroup where parameters('existingVNETName') is located.  You also need to deploy to the same location where that existing vnet is, and it may not be located in [resourceGroup().location]…

A couple things to check.